# Formatting problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting

For some reason, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4445/159) is ignoring all paragraph breaks and formatting for the last 40% of the question. It looks ok in preview, but not after saving.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in our "hoist out of the markdown parsing" code for `$..$` ranges.

Comment: There's another similar problem on edit 2 of http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/4471/revisions. I've rolled back to avoid the mess.

Comment: @rob another bug, we see what it is. stand by

Comment: @rob ok, that is fixed as well. Was HTML escaping issue with the hoisted sections.

Comment: Great. Thanks for doing it quickly.